# Keep a forked repo in sync after refactoring

Tags: git

I have two repos, **R1** and **R2**. **R2** is a fork of **R1**. Both are in Git

I want to do some refactoring on **R2**, I cant push these changes to **R1**. I would also like to keep **R2** in sync with **R1** with minimal overhead (as automated as possible, within reason). What I am wondering, is there way I could configure my **R2** repo to make life easier?

Here is an example.

```cpp
// R1 file.h
struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

```cpp
// R2 file.h

// I am providing some new doxygen comments that did not exist before
struct MyStruct{
  // some comment about variable that did not exist before
  int renamed_variable;
  // some comment about variable that did not exist before
  int b;
  
  void NewFunctionThatDidNotExist();
};
```

So then at some later time file.h changes in **R1**

```cpp
// R1 file.h
struct MyStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c; // Something that is added for new functionality I want
};
```

Right now if I tried to merge **R1** into **R2** to get the new changes, I would have a lot of merge conflicts because of all my changes in **R2**.

Comment: I assume you will most likely enter a world of pain and never-ending merge conflicts, but try playing around with `git rerere`, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere. Maybe it helps to soften the most tedious tasks.

Comment: "I would have a lot of merge conflicts because of all my changes in R2", yes, because you made changes in both parts. Sorry but I don't know what are you actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a commit by commit basis, go to the repo you want updated, and then using:

```
git cherry-pick numberornameofspecificcommit
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Some more info is on it here; I think cherry pick is your best option if you can't push all the changes from R2 to R1 & it would give you greater control to decide which commits have to be in R1.

Hopefully this helps! Let me know if you need other ideas or this doesn't work.

Comment: Is the numberornameofspecificcommit SHA the commit ID in R1 that added `int c`? Or do I need to pull R1 changes into R2 somehow? Maybe create a 'r1_snapshot' branch?

Comment: so let's say you want a commit number abc123 in R2 to be in R1
then you'd run git cherry-pick abc123 within the R1 directory

Comment: so you can look through whichever commit you want to be in R1 & then basically 'cherry pick' (lol) your favorite commits from R2 to be in R1

or vice versa
if you made a change in R1 that you wanted to be in R2, you could go to R2's directory, and run git cherry-pick and then the number of whatever commit you want included

Comment: and yes in your example the number would be the number of your commit that added int c